# Loading all GUI Screens at start of the program in QtQuick

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qt-quick

**This question is regarding QML, QtQuick 1.1, Qt 4.8.6**

I have seen source code of an embedded application, in which all the screens are loaded at start. For Example,

```
//Main.qml
Rectangle{                      //Base Container
    width:640
    height:480

    MainScreen{ id: main_screen}    //Individual screen files are given here
    SettingScreen1 { id:screen1}
    SettingScreen2 { id:screen2}
    HelpScreen1 {id: help_screen1}
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

and in the respective screen document, when a mouse area is clicked `the Value of Z` of the individual document is changed to make it appear front

```
//MainScreen.qml
Rectangle{
    width: 640
    height:480
    z:1
    //some buttons
    //Mousearea for next button
    onClicked: {screen1.z = 10}

    //Mousearea for back button
    onClicked: {screen1.z = 0}
    }
```

My question is,

**1.** As from main.qml all the children are created at once and only their visibility of stack order is changed. Is this a good method?

**2.** When so many children are loaded at beginning what happens if I have like 200 screens. What is the effect in CPU load at start and while operation.

**Is there any other method for screen transitions?**

**Other than component loader. I don`t want to use that feature**

How this code is converted and showed in display as an object?

I will be very happy is least you can give hints in comments.

Thanks!!

Comment: For screen transitions you can use [StackView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-stackview.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How GUI screen transition works in qml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655466/how-gui-screen-transition-works-in-qml)

Answer (score 3):

To your questions:

**1):** Bad Idea. Using the z-index needs the engine to determine that the lower items are hidden completely. You should help the enigne if you are sure about this (which would be the case here) by setting the `visibility` to false. Then however, you would not need to use the z-index at all. Don't use the z-index. Don't!

However this won't solve that you might have 200 possibly complex views in your memory.
The `Loader` you mentioned is already a better start.
You can use it in combination with the visibility to preload pages that are likely to be shown soon, and unload them once you are sure they are not shown anytime soon (within the next one or two clicks)

**2):** The effect is: Long time of unresponsivenes until everything is loaded. The documentation sais: Show a splash-screen if you want to do something like this. In order to show the splash-screen, show it, then use a `Loader` to load all the other stuff... But in general: Don't do it, if not absolutly necessary. Load dynamically. Never use the z-index to hide screens completely. Load only what needs to be loaded... I feel repetitive...

Comment: I agree with the combination of visibility and loader for appropriate screens. Thanks! One more question is, If i want to store the current settings, data and state of particular screens. What method do you suggest. Save in .txt or use visibility to hide or any other?

Comment: Seperate your data (model) and your view, so that the screens are stateless. This model could be stored by various methods, e.g. XML, JSON, SQL or what ever fits best to your system, if it needs to be persistent (survive a restart of the programm). If it is not necessary persistent, this is stored in QtObjects, that are not reloaded. Try to minimize the data in those QtObjects to only what is needed to restore the view.

Comment: Look into MVC/MVVM-Pattern

Comment: While `Loader` is proved to be useful, it comes with a certain overhead. Using few `Loader`s does not effect performances but having a lot could affect overall result. Hence, it really depends on the requirements and constraints of the created application. Generally speaking I would give [dynamic allocation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) a go, since you cannot access `StackView` here, the natural most-suited component for this use case.

Comment: The question has been for a large number of Screens. I agree with you, if the numer is low, and the frequency of changes is high, the overhead of the loader is supreme. For a larger number of screens, especially complex ones, the loader comes in useful. AFAIK, the loader is only another interface to an Item, whose children is set to a Component.createObject(). In my tests, the time was almost identical for a couple tens of thousands load-and-unload-cycles whether I used the JS-Functions or the `Loader`, at least in Qt5.

Comment: And I disagree with you on the StackView. The Screens seem to be *logicall* rather in parallel than stacked. So I would propose the `SwipeView` if it would be in QtQuick2

Comment: It's just "don't understimate" loader. That's what I'm trying to say. There's a presentation also on that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sM0u9_l4grM). `Loader`s were part of the slow-down in quick controls 1. As for the `StackView`, I can see your point but there is no information in the question to say that it's parallel or not. When you have a main view and settings and help like the OP said I see a common app workflow that works fine with `StackView`. Especially because on `StackView` only the needed panels are loaded.

Comment: Otherview you create all the panels at the beginning and parent the first to the StackView, then the lifetime is the same as the SwipeView. Or load them dynamically in the `SwipeView`. Then using one or the other does not make much difference, But anyhow, we have Qt 4.8 so that's just chit-chatting. I don't know, I feel like we are really talking about a matter of tastes here. :)

Comment: I don't know which "derM" you are refering to... But I like the presentation you linked.